# Can not get json data

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to read data from this link https://www.freecodecamp.com/json/cats.json
but it is not showing any data. What seems to be the problem ??
Here is my main page.The page is placed inside www folder of  wamp server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
    div.message {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    padding: 20px;
    } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>


     $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#click").on("click", function() {
          $.getJSON("https://www.freecodecamp.com/json/cats.json", function(json) {

            var html = "";
            // Only change code below this line.
            json.forEach(function(val){
              var keys=Object.keys(val);
              html+="<div class='cat'>";
              keys.forEach(function(key){
                html += "<strong>"+key+"</strong>: " + val[key] +             "<br>";

              });
              html += "</div><br>";

            });


            // Only change code above this line.

            $(".message").html(html);

          });
        });
      });
    </script>


<div id="tops">
<div class="well">
       <input type="text" id="user_id">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="click">See</button>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="here" class="well message">
</div>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="cros_web.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The remote server doesn't seem to support CORS so there's not much you could do from the client perspective. You may contact the site administrators to enable CORS for your domain if you want to be able to call it from a browser.

Comment: `Can anyone explain` you seem to know it's a CORS issue - you even tagged the post CORS, and have CORS in the title - so, to explain, the site does not allow cross origin resource sharing - which is why onerror triggers (because the request had an error, and status == 0 is a sure sign of CORS error)

Comment: @chris - "simple requests" merely avoid "CORS preflight", not "CORS" - the request in the question is a simple one - actually, scratch that, it's not a simple request due to the content-type header - but still, removing that wont "work around CORS" - there's no such thing as working around CORS

Comment: Then what should be the simple method with or without CORS to get data  from the site using JSON?? Please help

Comment: @PHPglue - 1) if the client doesn't have XHR2, then they are using a VERY old browser - 2) there's no problem with how the OP handles asynchronicity in the code as shown

Comment: @newbie - the only way to not have CORS issue is to proxy the request through your own server - that would require you to know some server side coding depending on what is available on your server

Comment: @JaromandaX I am using wamp server

Comment: so, the `p` in `wamp` stands for `PHP` - search how to create a "proxy" for requests - it can be done in about 3 lines of PHP (if that) for a get request - however I would suggest search for "php proxy request" and find a library you are comfortable with

Comment: @JaromandaX i am following this method to get json data now 
but it is not working as well. Can u help??